# what is start-x and start-y in ionic ion-content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic(though I know angular basics). I am exploring ionic2. I have been reading about ion-content and its attributes:- I have encountered `start-x` and `start-y` attributes in the docs. I have also see explored following [code point link](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/rxysG), where sample chat UI is shown and where start-y is used.

Docs says that :-

> `start-x`
>
> Initial horizontal scroll position. Default 0.
>
> `start-y`
>
> Initial vertical scroll position. Default 0.

However, I am not clear about scroll position. What does it implies ? Does it imply where scroll bar will be placed ? Does it imply scroll values ? Can anyone illustrate it with a diagram ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: generally things of this nature are about where the scrollbar will be when it loads. So if the scrollbar can go down to say 150, it'll start at 10. Hope that made sense.

Comment: @Jhecht, still it's not clear. Do you mean that start-y specifies y-cordinate where scroll bar's top will be situated ? Can you give a suitable example ?

Comment: haven't used ionic, you could test it by setting the height of an element at the top to 10px high and then set the scroll-y coordinate to 10. If you can't see that element, then you know it must be pixels. If not, it must be something else.